# Magento how to trigger a 404 redirect from controller when extension overwrite root layout node

Tags: magento, layout

I've written an extension for Magento which will initiate a 404 redirect from the controller under certain circumstances. The code in the controller that causes the 404 redirect is:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
$pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_no_route');
if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
    $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
}
```

This code is accessed via the URL www.mysite.com/mymodule/index/action?name=value and the redirect is triggered based on 'value'.

However, because because my module contains a layout update which overwrites the root node:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mynamespace_mymodule_index_action>
        <block type="mymodule/list" name="root" template="mynamespace/mymodule/list.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </mynamespace_mymodule_index_action>
</layout>
```

the 404 redirect is showing a blank (white) page, which contains the following HTML:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerdivshade">    
        <div id="outerdivpadding">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
                        <div class="main">
                            <div class="col-main"></div>
                            <div class="col-left sidebar"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm guessing that by updating of the root node I've left a layout structure that the redirect code cannot work with to create the complete 404 page.

By removing the if statement and leaving just the code:

```
$this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
```

everything works, but I don't understand the pros and cons of doing this.

Interestingly the above code works correctly on Magento 1.6, but not on 1.7.

I'd appreciate any comments on the *right* way of including a working 404 redirect, but still allowing me to use my own root node in the layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

For showing the 404 page you can call the `norouteAction` of the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class.

```
$this->norouteAction();
return;
```

The 404 page can be edited in the backend. The page has the title `404 Not Found 1`.
You can also put in there your custom layout update XML.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the various ways of generating the 404. So far I can see three methods: $this->norouteAction(), then there is $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute'); and finally there is Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)

Comment: For Magento 2 what we have 2 use?